# How to render view template by jQuery in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need to render view template by jQuery. I have template 'category.html.erb' and file 'category.js.erb' with following code:

```
    $("#block").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :template => 'category') %>");
```

but it doesn't render category view template.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Try
$("#block").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:template => 'category')) %>");

I prefer rendering a partial like:
$("#block").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'category')) %>");